# Any explanation for this behavior?

Tags: c, linux, file, file-io, text-files

Am writing a code to reverse a text file.
ex: abc should become cba

I wrote the code fine and it works.
But I noticed this peculiar behavior.
If I give the reversed output as the input again, it skips the last character of the reversed input file.
How come it works fine for the first time and skips a character next time?

Here's the code:

```
int main(){
    int fin, fout;
    char c[1];
    fin = open("input.txt",O_RDONLY);
    fout = open("reverse_input.txt",O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC);
    lseek(fin, -2, SEEK_END);
    do{
        read(fin, c, 1);
        write(fout,c,1);
    }while(lseek(fin, -2, SEEK_CUR) >=0);
    close(fin);
    close(fout);    
    return 0;
}
```

Am guessing am missing out some sort of EOF character...

Comment: To replicate my results, rename the reverse_input.txt file to input.txt and create an empty file reverse_input.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the last char from fin as the last char to fout.

Comment: That should do it.  Be sure it's the right value. Find it, save it, and the write it out after the while, right before you close the file.

Comment: you writes very short answers, but indeed nice pick

Comment: I have to write short answers; only way I can beat you! :)